# Why http1.1 still has multiple tcp connections

Tags: http, tcp

http1.1 used a permanent connection to process client request, why it still established multiple tcp connections. for example, I use open the site "www.baidu.com" in google chrome, and I found the tcp connections on my computer as following:

tcp        0      0 192.168.1.123:45939     115.239.210.26:80       ESTABLISHED 2801/chrome
tcp        0      0 192.168.1.123:45955     115.239.210.26:80       ESTABLISHED 2801/chrome
tcp        0      0 192.168.1.123:45938     115.239.210.26:80       ESTABLISHED 2801/chrome
tcp        0      0 192.168.1.123:45937     115.239.210.26:80       ESTABLISHED 2801/chrome

"115.239.210.26" is the site's IP address.

Somebody help me ! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is for displaying the web page faster by downloading the various assets ( (java)scripts, images etc ) in parallel. In addition to it, the client side javascript may also decide to open multiple connections to the server.

There are setting to reduce/increase the number of simultaneous open connections in various browsers. 4 is the default in almost all the browsers.

Comment: And, while the HTTP 1.1 spec. says no more than 2 concurrent connection to the same address hould be set up, most browsers use more than that (e.g. for chrome the default max is 6 concurrent connections)